# How to get the Parent Process ID by giving a Process ID in Linux using C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, pid

I know it's possible to get ppid information from `/proc/PID/status` but I just want to use it as the backup plan.

So, is it possible to get the PPID by giving a PID number? `getppid(2)` can only get the PPID of *current* process so it's not helpful in this situation.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Failing access to a lib, you can always read `/proc/$pid/status` where `$pid` is, of course, the PID you're interested in.  Look for the line prefixed by "PPid:"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use get_proc_stats function to do this. But you need to install the libproc-dev library.

Here is an example :

```
proc_t p_info;
get_proc_stats(pid_num, &p_info);
int parent_pid = p_info.ppid;
```